# Split string to new line

Tags: php

I am trying to split a 90 character long string onto three 30 length strings. I cannot simply chop the long string into three lines(worst case scenario) as words in string will split. The code I have tried is as follows(but doesn't work), please help

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

    $str = "test string more and more text very long string can be upto length of 90";
    $line1 = $line2 = $line3 = "";

    $temp = explode(" ", $str);
    //var_dump($temp);

    for($i=0; $i<count($temp); $i++){
        if(strlen($line1) < 30){
            $line1. = $temp[$i]." ";

        }else if(strlen($line2) < 30) {
            $line2. = $temp[$i]." ";

        }else if(strlen($line3) < 30) {
            $line2. = $temp[$i]." ";

        }
    }

    //var_dump($line1);
?>
```

I am trying to add as many words in $line1 from $temp as possible and then to $line2 ....

Comment: Could you just loop through the string every 30 chars, if that spot isn't a space, go forward or backwards to the nearest space?

Comment: thanks for reply..trying to implement this in code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, I would say that that's the [`wordwrap`](http://php.net/wordwrap) function is for:

```
$str = "test string more and more text very long string can be upto length of 90";
$wrapped = wordwrap($str, 30, "\n", true);
list($line1, $line2, $line3) = explode("\n", $wrapped . "\n\n");
```

(The extra `\n`s on `$wrapped` are to prevent errors in case fewer than 3 lines are made.)

However, your problem is a bit different.  `wordwrap` will sometimes make a 4th line rather than cut a word in half, which is what you need to do.  `wordwrap` will only ever make a 4th line if cutting a word is required, so perhaps try this:

```
$str = "test string more and more terxt very long string can be upto length of 90 bla bla bla3rr33";
$maxLen = 30;
$wrapped = wordwrap($str, $maxLen, "\n", true);
list($line1, $line2, $line3, $line4) = explode("\n", $wrapped . "\n\n\n");
if ($line4 !== '') {
    //fallback case: we have to split words in order to fit the string properly in 3 lines
    list($line1, $line2, $line3) = array_map('trim', str_split($str, $maxLen));
}
```

There is one bad thing that this code can do: it will sometimes split two words when it only needs to split one.  I'll leave it to you to figure out how to fix that if you need to.

Comment: OP should use this. Looks like this function has been around for a while and I have never used it. Learn something new every day.

Comment: @Austin : doesn't work for string "$str = "test string more and more terxt very long string can be upto length of 90 bla bla bla3rr33";" In such case it should chop the $str..i guess, i'll loop through the string for 30 chars and check for spaces as suggested by wade

Comment: @kennyben You are right; your problem is actually a bit different than what `wordwrap` does.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative, assuming all of the words are separated by spaces.

```
$words = explode(" ", $string);
$chunks = array_chunk($words, 30);

foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo implode(" ", $chunk) . "\n\n\n";    
}
```

<sup>*We're harnessing [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode), [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) to do as required.*</sup>

[**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#DZFB0HeJW)

---

The way it works above is as follows:

- Take the string and split it into an array of words (with the delimiter being the empty space - `" "`)
- Now we'll `array_chunk` (*chunk*) the array into 3 seperate arrays of 30 items.
- Now we'll loop through that array of chunks and `implode()` the array, making it a string again with the same space delimiter - `" "`.

And viola, you've chunked it and split the string as you desire.

Comment: sorry but comment provided by Wade makes more sense..just trying to implement the code. Thanks for reply anyways

Comment: @kennyben The above will always split it correctly via characters (*words*). Look at the [example](http://www.tehplayground.com/#DZFB0HeJW)

Comment: yes, thank you. but if you read the question this is not what we are trying to achieve.

Comment: @kennyben Whoops, just read it properly, give me a second and I'll try whip something up quick.